# Font Awesome not working in Laravel 5.8 admin panel

Tags: php, css, laravel, font-awesome

I've used Font Awesome in my applications many times. However, when I installed a free admin theme in the panel, it's no longer working. I tried using a CDN and also downloaded the CSS file from their website. I've
tried everything; nothing is working. It displays square blocks instead of icons. It's working on other pages, but not on this one.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Custom fontawesome font/icons for this template-->
    <link href="{{asset('admin/css/all.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body id="page-top">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark static-top">
    <a class="btn btn-link btn-sm text-white order-1 order-sm-0" id="sidebarToggle" href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="navbar-brand mr-1 pl-3" href="#">Admin Panel</a>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked your developer tools if the CSS is correctly loaded and have you made sure the classes within your css fit the classes within your HTML?

Comment: does same icon works in other pages. i meant if  `fa fa-phone` does it works in other pages

Comment: view the page source and click on the CSS link. of font-awesome. if it is showing the CSS code with a file that means it is integrated successfully.

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url('admin/css/all.min.css')}}">
```